# Block git commit with certain 'flag'?

Tags: git

Sometimes when you need to quickly test something, you replace some variables in the code, which should **never** make it to production. E.g. fill in some credentials, just to check the connection locally, rather than fetching the acceptance logs. This data should just never-ever-ever reach production, and should actually be removed before committing to the versioning system (git in our case). I was wondering if there was some kind of magical "tag" which you could put in comments for instance, which would make git block the commit. Something like:

```
somewildparam= 10
anotherparam= fancy_headers
# ![GIT_BLOCK]!
thesecretpassprasetomtgoxcoldwallet=oopsimsorry
```

And upon `git commit -am"Yeah I fixed something!"`:

```
git: COMMIT FAILED, REASON: GIT_BLOCK tag found. This could cost you money!
```

*Disclaimer:*
As we all know, a good programmer would ** never ** do such a thing. So, let's say I'm just asking for a friend.

Comment: Related, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32356457/git-pre-commit-hook-to-find-text-in-files

Comment: Ok, seeing the duplicate-mark, it is apparently not a thing in git, but instead solved with a custom pre-commit hook.

Comment: @poke not a duplicate of that, OP is asking to prevent a commit, not a push.

Comment: @1615903 I know, the accepted answer covers a pre-commit hook though. I believe OP should be able to work from that.

Comment: @poke Ah true, missed that.

Comment: I've been told that "same answer" is not "same question" and doesn't qualify as a duplicate.