# Git hook rule to not allow push if CSS specific property is not meet the consition

Tags: css, git, hook, commit

I would like to find the way for git hook to prevent commit and push if the z-index has been use and the value if below 1000. But I did google for it but I could not find any suitable solution for it.

Do you have any solution for it?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, that would be a [server-side hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#_server_side_hooks), like a pre-receive hook.
That way, you don't have to deploy a hook to all developers: any developer pushing an incorrect file would see their push rejected.
The other approach is a client-side hook, [like a pre-commit hook similar to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43601298/6309)

In a pre-receive hook, [you can list each file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15160974/6309) and, if their are CSS, get their content

```
git show commit:filepath
```

You can then grep for `z-index` and check their associated value.